# Cannot locate tasks that match ':composeApp:compileJava' as task 'compileJava' is ambiguous in project ':composeApp'

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform

```
Cannot locate tasks that match ':composeApp:compileJava' as task 'compileJava' is ambiguous in project ':composeApp'. Candidates are: 'compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac', 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac', 'compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac', 'compileReleaseJavaWithJavac', 'compileReleaseUnitTestJavaWithJavac'.

* Try:
> Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks.
> For more on name expansion, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.4/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:name_abbreviation in the Gradle documentation.
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.4/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
BUILD FAILED in 189ms
```

I have created the project from the jetbrains website.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It looks like a bug in the template. According to [Multiplatform: Cannot locate tasks that match ':composeApp:compileJava'](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-63092/Multiplatform-Cannot-locate-tasks-that-match-composeAppcompileJava), calling `gradle :composeApp:run` from Run Anything works on my machine.

Comment: This worked for me as well.

Comment: Worked for me as well.

Comment: worked for me 

Comment: this works plus see how to get debugger attached here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77480498/kotlin-multiplatform-desktopmain-cannot-be-executed

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Android Studio on Mac, from the terminal type:
`./gradlew :composeApp:run`

Answer (score 5):

In Mac, run the following command:

```
./gradlew :composeApp:run
```

For Windows, it's similar:

```
.\gradlew :composeApp:run
```

If it doesn't work on Windows, try running the Mac command in a bash terminal or with WSL.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue on Android Studio and running the same project in IntelliJ Idea gave me no errors and the build ran fine.